# simultaneous mounts of devpts

Tags: linux, mount, devices

I want to create multiple chroot environments, but I faced the issue with mounting devpts

Here is STR:

```
> mkdir -p {1,2}/{proc,sys,dev/pts}
> mount -v -t sysfs   sysfs    1/sys/
> mount -v -t proc    proc     1/proc/
> mount -v -o bind    /dev     1/dev/
> mount -v -o bind    /dev/pts 1/dev/pts

> mount -v -t sysfs   sysfs    2/sys/
> mount -v -t proc    proc     2/proc/
> mount -v -o bind    /dev     2/dev/

> mount | grep "/root/"  | awk '{print $3}' | sort
/root/1/dev
/root/1/dev/pts
/root/1/proc
/root/1/sys
/root/2/dev
/root/2/proc
/root/2/sys
```

If I mount '/dev/pts' to the '2/dev/pts' directory, I will get duplicate mount points

```
> mount -v -o bind    /dev/pts 2/dev/pts
mount: /dev/pts bound on /root/2/dev/pts.
```

As you can see after these actions system creates two mount points for '/root/1/dev/pts':

```
> mount | grep "/root/"  | awk '{print $3}' | sort
/root/1/dev
/root/1/dev/pts <---
/root/1/dev/pts <---
/root/1/proc
/root/1/sys
/root/2/dev
/root/2/dev/pts <---
/root/2/proc
/root/2/sys
```

If I unmount the first mount point, the second one will be unmounted too

```
> umount -v /root/1/dev/pts
umount: /root/1/dev/pts unmounted
> mount | grep "/root/"  | awk '{print $3}' | sort
/root/1/dev
/root/1/dev/pts <---
/root/1/proc
/root/1/sys
/root/2/dev
/root/2/proc
/root/2/sys
```

Could you please explain to me why it happens?